# Leafiest Tropical Tree

Tags: trees, compost, plant-recommendations

I currently live in tropical country Philippines and I would like to plant or graft the most leafiest tree serving 2 purpose; first to have a better shade, like I said we live in a tropical climate and leafy trees provide a cool and shady place. secondly, tree leaves are useful for composting so I'm searching for the best one. It's a plus if it can grow the least possible time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider growing following:-

- [Teak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teak)

  Broad shape, Grows faster(approx 9 mtr/year), durability in weather and against insects.
- [Acacia Mangium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acacia_mangium)

   Grows 3-5 mtr/year, fixes nitrogen in the soil, susceptible to termites.

References:- 
http://www.ehow.com/list_5929683_fast-growing-tropical-trees.html 
http://www.funtrivia.com/askft/Question13317.html

Comment: A little description of the trees will provide a better answer and more upvotes